# How do I edit setting in a paragraph?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to edit a particular setting in a stanza in a file. Here is the format on my file:

```
[common_string_test1]
setting = 0

[common_string_test2]
setting = 1
```

Say I want to change 'setting' to 0. How can I grep for the common string and determine if I need to change the setting or not.

EDIT: I am able to grep for the common string using `awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/common_string/`. How do I add to this so that I can change the parameter within that paragraph?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: To do this properly, you'll need a full-blown configuration-file parser. Standard line-oriented tools aren't appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

something like this will work, but it might be fragile...

```
$ awk '!NF{f=0} !f&&/^\[common_string/{f=1} f&&$1=="setting"{$3=0}1' file
```